# Get only domain from any URL

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to get these URLs:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ -> https://www.facebook.com/
http://www.facebook.com/ -> http://www.facebook.com/
https://www.facebook.com -> https://www.facebook.com
https://www.facebook.com/awdawdaw/dawdwad -> https://www.facebook.com/
```

My regex is: `/(https*:\/\/.+(\/|\b))/gi`.

First 3 URLs were been returned well. But when there is something after `/` character, it will also match that characters and I don't want it. What should I do as next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below negated character class based regex.

```
\bhttps?:\/\/[^\/]+\/?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sY8gB5/1)

Comment: Exact same answer I was posting but was a few seconds late +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location.hostname
```

Hope I got you correctly :)

Comment: This will only work if he's trying to get the URL of the page that the user is on - not for example if they where inputting addresses into a textbox.

But yes - avoid using regex where ever possible.

Comment: I don't see any textbox word on question body. but you right, that works only if you want to get the domain of browser's address bar (maybe `any URL` means URL of any source ;) )

Comment: I know that, but question is about to get another URLs (what would my users send).